# ¿Por qué y cómo puedo hacer que la ip que obtenga mi función PHP no sea la del VPS?

Tags: php, ip

Os explico, es un poco extraño, la verdad es la primera vez que me ha pasado. He comprado un dominio y una vps, he configurado vestaCP y las dns. Total, que cuando subo mis archivos al panel, la petición de `$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` muestra la IP del servidor VPS, no la del cliente. ¿Cómo podría solucionar esto? Porque básicamente de la IP dependen muchas funciones relacionadas a la seguridad. Un saludo 
 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Dejo por aquí algo más de code y un attachment:

```
    $key = 'Ocultada por privacidad[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]';

/*
* Retrieve the user's IP address. 
* You could also pull this from another source such as a database.
* 
*/
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


// Retrieve additional (optional) data points which help us enhance fraud scores.
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
$user_language = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];

// Set the strictness for this query. (0 (least strict) - 3 (most strict))
$strictness = 1;

// You may want to allow public access points like coffee shops, schools, corporations, etc...
$allow_public_access_points = 'true';

// Reduce scoring penalties for mixed quality IP addresses shared by good and bad users.
$lighter_penalties = 'false';

// Create parameters array.
$parameters = array(
    'user_agent' => $user_agent,
    'user_language' => $user_language,
    'strictness' => $strictness,
    'allow_public_access_points' => $allow_public_access_points,
    'lighter_penalties' => $lighter_penalties
);

/* User & Transaction Scoring
* Score additional information from a user, order, or transaction for risk analysis
* Please see the documentation and example code to include this feature in your scoring:
* https://www.ipqualityscore.com/documentation/proxy-detection/transaction-scoring
* This feature requires a Premium plan or greater
*/

// Format Parameters
$formatted_parameters = http_build_query($parameters);

// Create API URL
$url = sprintf(
    'https://www.ipqualityscore.com/api/json/ip/%s/%s?%s', 
    $key,
    $ip, 
    $formatted_parameters
);

// Fetch The Result
$timeout = 5;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

$json = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Decode the result into an array.
$result = json_decode($json, true);
$fraud = $result['fraud_score'];


// Check to see if our query was successful.




if ($fraud > 35) {
    

        echo $ip;

}
else{

}
```

Comment: Podria estar vinculado a la falta de mod_remoteip... ¿usas nginx o apache? Aun asi, yo dejé vestacp hace un tiempo y prefiero hestiacp que tiene mejor mantenimiento y viene a ser lo mismo pero con mas gente detras... ademas la migracion de vestacp a hestiacp es compatible

Comment: A nivel de código, si solo lo necesitas ahi, podrias probar con `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];`

Comment: @masterguru uso Apache, voy a probar con ese code

Comment: @masterguru ha funcionado, gracias!!

Comment: Crea tu mismo la respuesta.  Así no quedará pendiente. El caso es que eso no ocurre siempre en VestaCP, más bien solo en Ubuntu creo. Yo lo encontré surfeando un poco pero no se ver el motivo real pues tampoco conozco exactamente tu entorno ni tu configuración de Apache, así que prefiero no hacerlo yo ni liarte con más cambios de configuración que tampoco se si te funcionarian. Pon algo así como "En mi caso lo he solucionado con blabla" y yasta. Con un poco de suerte aparecerá otro explicándolo mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He logrado solucionarlo con el siguiente code:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
```